# Trying to access a injected dependency outside controller method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there possible to access a injected dependency on controller outside on it?

```js
function clienteCreateController(ClientesService, recuperarEndereco) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.pesquisarCep = pesquisarCep;
}


function pesquisarCep(cep) {
  recuperarEndereco.find(cep)
    .success(function(data) {
      parseEndereco(data).bind(this);
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      // showAlertDanger(vm, 'Cep inválido.');
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

I'm calling the method from a button click.

Thanks

Comment: Can you define the vm.pesquisarCep within your controller body only ?

Comment: I'm trying to declare it outside, because it's used in another places.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can access the parameter `recuperarEndereco` in the outside function `pesquisarCep`. Because inside the execution context in function `pesquisarCep`, the variable is `recuperarEndereco` is not declared at all. Same as this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dLhmozf3/. It reports error:

```
function outsite () {
    console.log('param: ' + param);
}

var f = function (param) {
    var me = outsite;
    me();
};

f();
```

You need to define the outside function like: `function pesquisarCep(cep, recuperarEndereco) { ...`. And call it like `pesquisarCep(cep, recuperarEndereco)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tought that was some javascript magic with closures or whatever that let me access the variables declared at controller function.